# Input Touchscreen for mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have four buttons at the bottom, notes would then fall from the top of the screen, I am not sure how to code the touchscreen part for mobile, I have it working for pc format, but I am not sure what I need to change for it to work.

I have 2 scripts, one for the buttons and then one for every note falling down.

This is what I have at the moment:
For the buttons:

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
        {
            theSR.sprite = pressedImage;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(keyToPress))
        {
            theSR.sprite = defaultImage;
        }
    }
```

For the Notes:
void Update()

```
 {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
        {
            if(canBePressed)
            {
                gameObject.SetActive(false);

                //GameManager.instance.NoteHit();


                //Determine if player hits the note normal, good, perfect
                if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y) > 0.25)
                {
                    GameManager.instance.NormalHit();
                    Instantiate(hitEffect, transform.position, hitEffect.transform.rotation);
                }
                else if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y) > 0.05f)
                {
                    GameManager.instance.GoodHit();
                    Instantiate(goodEffect, transform.position, goodEffect.transform.rotation);

                }
                else
                {
                    GameManager.instance.PerfectHit();
                    Instantiate(perfectEffect, transform.position, perfectEffect.transform.rotation);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly if it was PC only but I just don't know what to change for it to buttons to react exactly the same way in mobile as it would on PC

Comment: When dealing with multi-platform inputs consider using [LeanTouch](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/lean-touch-30111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer depends on how you intend to get the user input on mobile. There are 2 ways to do this if I think of off my head.

The first would be to get input touch screen position and check if the position on the x axis is in one of 4 compartments for the nots. You can get that with [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

The second, you can actually use the UI buttons from Unity and they work on all platforms. So you can test on PC and the upload to your phone to have it working the same way.

Hope any of this helps you!